# Single file Qt4 demo

Tags: qt, qt4, moc

Sometimes you need to create a **very** simple single file application in Qt4. However it's problematic since you are always doing the CPP/H separation, and then the main() is in another file...

Any ideas how to do this in a single file? As quick as dirty as possible.

Comment: I like the idea but not how you did it :) You should post a real question and then submit the code above as an answer to your own question. Will get you a badge, too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example that shows how to do this in a single file. Just throw this in a new directory, save it as "main.cpp" and then run `qmake -project; qmake; make` to compile.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui/QPushButton>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0){
        button = new QPushButton("Hello, world!", this);
    }
private:
    QPushButton *button;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Two tricks in this demo:

1. First is how to call "qmake -project" to create a *.pro file with the files in the current directory automagically. The target name by default is the name of the directory, so choose it wisely.
2. Second is to #include *.moc in the CPP file, to ask moc to preprocess the CPP files for QObject definitions.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to build a quick prototype, using Python and [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) is even more compact:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.button = QPushButton("Hello, world!", self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

No need to call `qmake` or to bother with `.moc` files.

Comment: I use it many times to send bugs to Trolltech/QtSoftware/Nokia. I am not sure PyQt4 is the best way of doing it.

Comment: As I said: "If you need to build a quick prototype". Keep in mind that other people might have slightly different needs.